# wpf input data into datagrid from user interface

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

I am pretty new to wpf and vb.net. I am trying to do a simple user interface where the user can enter the no:of rows he require in a datagrid then the background vb.net code populates the datagrid with the entered no:of rows.

Now the user should be able to enter the text data into the rows, and the background code should be able to access the data in that row further use.

My code is as below:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="855">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DaGrFCC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="4,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="823" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DaGrColNo" Header="No" FontFamily="MetaPlusLF"/>                
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="DaGrCoSel" Header="Select"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="But" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="158,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TeBoNo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="29,252,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>

</Grid>
```

and the code that runs in background is

```
Class MainWindow 
  Private Sub But_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles But.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    i = TeBoNo.Text
    For j As Integer = DaGrFCC.Items.Count + 1 To i
      DaGrFCC.Items.Add(New Object)
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

I am able to get the rows but when I click on the text box column it gives an exception saying,"edititem is not allowed in this view".

Any help will be useful.

Comment: If you're that new to VB.Net i suggest you go C# asap... Oh, and in case you haven't done winforms (i.e. the forms-like code is unintentional), read up on mvvm a bit(and in case you have - read **a lot** :P)...

Comment: To the question, then: you optimally do that (in wpf) by binding your datagrid's `ItemsSource` to a collection (`List`, `ObservableCollection`, etc.) and add items to that... My guess would be that whatever the `UIElements` that are being added to the `Items` `ItemCollection` are, they don't implement `IEditableObject` (hence - cannot be edited as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) @ "Editing")... You can try setting `IsReadOnly` to false jic of course...

Comment: @StefanDenchev I would initially like to have my rows all empty. By binding it to the List wouldn't it fill up the grid? I have set the IsReadOnly to false in the datagrid as well as in the column but still the same problem persists.

Comment: Then it's probably as I said... Why would it if the list is empty?

Comment: @StefanDenchev Actually I am trying to make a UI like an exel sheet but each column with a differnet control element so the user can input values in the cell. So to achive this is `DataGrid` the right control to use or do i need to change?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, yes, in my opinion it should suffice... But this is getting horribly off-topic, i'd suggest we move this to chat but i believe you need 20 reputation for that :(...